# indexing subsets within a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

df is a pandas dataframe.

this gives me my young subjects:

```
df_young = df[df['Age']<40]
```

this gives me my old subjects:

```
df_old = df[df['Age']>60]
```

Now I want to get my middleaged subjects with something like (invalid syntax):

```
df_middleage = df[df['Age']< 40 and < 60]
```

Does anyone know how to do that efficiently? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&`:

```
df_middleage = df[(df['Age'] > 40) & (df['Age'] < 60)]
```

See the docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: Thank you. That works - but the greater-than signs should be like that: df_middleage = df[(df['Age']> 40) & (df['Age']< 60)] to get the middleaged